# How can I add a button to close a modal in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm displaying a modal using `present` in Swift and I want to add a button on the top left of it so I will be able to close the modal by pressing it. How can I do that?

```
@IBAction func touchCreateEvent(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.present(HomeViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

This is where I display the modal. I want that button because on the previous iOS version we don't have the swipe down animation in order to dismiss the modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HomeViewController inside IBAction do:

```
@IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```